# Mapping extension of HashMap to Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, oracle11g, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I decided to create the following object:

```
public class ScoreMap<T> extends HashMap<T, Double>
```

And I would like to save them in the DB:

```
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Map<String, Double> keywords = new ScoreMap<>();
```

Which works perfectly. Everything is saved as expected.

---

Now, when retrieving, it seems I can't return an ScoreMap without TypeCasting:

```
public ScoreMap<String> getKeywords()
{
    return (ScoreMap<String>)keywords;
}
```

and doing so I get the following error:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/myApp] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentMap cannot be cast to entity.ScoreMap (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->entity.Document["document_knowledge"]->entity.DocumentKnowledge_$$_jvst505_2["keywords"])] with root cause
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentMap cannot be cast to entity.ScoreMap
```

---

I tried changing the **ScoreMap** to:

```
public class ScoreMap<T> extends HashMap<T, Double> implements Map<T, Double>
```

With same results.

---

I need to return a **ScoreMap** to use other methods there.

I know I could just **foreach** and recreate the object easily but I'd love I could avoid that.

So which is the best aproach to this situation? I'm just designing this plainly wrong or I'm missing something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you another approach. *Delegation*.

Instead of *extending* `HashMap<K, V>`, why don't you just implement the `Map<K, V>` interface and accept another instance of `Map` as constructor argument?

```
class ScoreMap<T> implements Map<T, Double> {
   private final Map<T, Double> delegate;

   ScoreMap(final Map<T, Double> delegate) {
      this.delegate = delegate;
   }

   ...

   @Override
   public Double get(final Object key) {
      // Apply custom logic, if needed
      return delegate.get(key);
   }

   // And so on...
}
```

Then, use a `getter` and a `setter`

```
@Entity
@...
class YourEntity {
   ...

   private Map<String, Double> keywords;

   @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   public ScoreMap<String> getKeywords() {
      // This is fine as we know the Map will always be a ScoreMap
      return (ScoreMap<String>) keywords;
   }

   public void setKeywords(final Map<String, Double> keywords) {
      this.keywords = new ScoreMap<>(keywords);
   }
}
```

As you can seem each time Hibernate will *set* the `Map`, you'll wrap it inside your `ScoreMap`, having additional and custom logic.

And for your interest, the Hibernate `PersistentMap` does implement the `Map` interface, so it can be accepted by your `ScoreMap`.

---

The Hibernate documentation states

> As a requirement persistent collection-valued fields must be declared
>   as an interface type (see Example 7.2, “Collection mapping using
>   @OneToMany and @JoinColumn”). The actual interface might be
>   java.util.Set, java.util.Collection, java.util.List, java.util.Map,
>   java.util.SortedSet, java.util.SortedMap or anything you like
>   ("anything you like" means you will have to write an implementation of
>   org.hibernate.usertype.UserCollectionType).

So I'll edit my example above.
And as last resort, you could give a look at `UserCollectionType`

Comment: I thought about this but that means \@Override all the Map methods which I wanted to avoid by extending HashMap.

An other issue is: Why would this work? If I try the same with a HashMap : private HashMap<String, Double> keywords= new HashMap<>(); then I get: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a \@OneToMany, \@ManyToMany or \@CollectionOfElements

Comment: @epsilonmajorquezero don't be scared of overriding all these methods. I do this kind of thing a lot (I love the delegation pattern) and I've never had a problem. Keep your custom methods up in the class code.

See the updated answer for the other point

Comment: this.keywords = new ScoreMap<>(keywords);

This is more or less what I did in the end while I awaited for an answer: Just that I did it on the getter: return new ScoreMap<>(keywords); This way everything works, I don't have all that code for the delegation (which would be muuuch longer than the two small methods ScoreMap currently has). I kindda expected Spring to be smart enough to make the conversion from Map to ScoreMap itself but well, it is what it is :) Much thanks! I'll take a look at the delegation patter to learn a bit more about it!

Comment: Just don't forget to use `@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)` on the getter ...